# Can you use CGEventSetLocation to move the mouse?

Tags: core-graphics, mouse

I have a small program that should move the mouse to a certain point (in this case, 100,100) when it goes past 500 pixels from the left of the screen. The CGEventTap correctly receives the kCGEventMouseMoved events, but CGEventSetLocation seems to only move events such as mouseUp, not MouseMoved.

Is it possible to move the mouse with CGEventSetLocation? If not, is there some other way to do it?

I've included my code here:

```
CGEventRef 
mouse_filter(CGEventTapProxy proxy, CGEventType type, CGEventRef event, void *refcon) {
    if (type != kCGEventMouseMoved)
        return event;

    CGPoint point = CGEventGetLocation(event);
    CGPoint target = CGPointMake(500,point.y);
    if (point.x >= 500){
        CGEventSetLocation(event,target);
        printf("(%f,%f)\n", point.x, point.y);
    }
    return event;
}

int 
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    CFRunLoopSourceRef runLoopSource;
    CGEventMask event_mask;
    event_mask = (1 << kCGEventMouseMoved);
    CFMachPortRef eventTap = CGEventTapCreate(kCGSessionEventTap, kCGHeadInsertEventTap, 0, event_mask, mouse_filter, NULL);

    if (!eventTap) {
        NSLog(@"Couldn't create event tap!");
        exit(1);
    }

    runLoopSource = CFMachPortCreateRunLoopSource(kCFAllocatorDefault, eventTap, 0);

    CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), runLoopSource, kCFRunLoopCommonModes);

    CGEventTapEnable(eventTap, true);

    CFRunLoopRun();

    CFRelease(eventTap);
    CFRelease(runLoopSource);
    [pool release];

    exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confusingly, [the function you want](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/Quartz_Services_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGWarpMouseCursorPosition) is actually not in Quartz Event Services, but [Quartz Display Services](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/Quartz_Services_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001070).

Comment: Funny that you should point this out, I actually discovered it about 2.5 hours ago and I was going to answer my own question but decided to give the community a chance. I'm giving you the accepted answer. If you happen to know whether or not I should use CGAssociateMouseAndMouseCursor(0), please let me know. It seems like this might be beneficial?

Comment: @JonathonG As the docs say, “When you call this function to disconnect the cursor and mouse, all events received by your application have a constant absolute location but contain mouse delta (change in X and Y) data.” So you would only disconnect the cursor from the mouse if you want the mouse to act like a joystick. Useful mainly for 3D games and certain kinds of controls (Final Cut has one or two that use it).